# How to prevent reset of session timeout timer when using handler (ashx)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, handler, session-timeout

I'm using a handler to poll certain information out my application. I've got some questions about using the handler in combination with session timeout:

1. Does a call to the handler reset the session timeout timer?
2. If so, are there ways to prevent a reset of this timer?

Due to security reasons I would not like my handler to be the cause that my user is logged on indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Run the handler in a different web app

Comment: Wow... is there absolutely no way of doing this in the same app?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to do some kind of manual session timeout handling. Something like this:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["LastAccessTime"] != null && (DateTime)Session["LastAccessTime"] < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20))
        Session.Abandon();

    if(Request.RawUrl != "/MyHandler.ashx")
        Session["LastAccessTime"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: No, it's separate. Either the .NET session times out first, which is fine, or this timer does. But this timer is unaffected by calls to the handler.

Comment: Yeah, but a session timeout is something that happens on the server when the client doesn't connect (it will fire a Session_End). Your solution only works when a request comes in and is actually timed out.

Comment: But you're polling frequently, so I don't see why that would be a problem? I'm not saying it's the most elegant solution out there, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.